# Python: is there a maximum of values the write() functions could process?

Tags: python, max, text-files, default-value

I´m new in python so I would be thankful for every help...
My problem is the following:
I wrote a program in python analysing gene sequences of a huge database (more than 600 genes). With the help of the write() function the program should insert the results in a text file - one result per gene. Opening my output file, there are only the first genes followed by "..." followed by the last gene.

Is there a maximum this function could process? How do I make python write all results?

relevant part of code:

```
fasta_df3 = pd.read_table(fasta_out3, delim_whitespace=True, names=
('qseqid','sseqid', 'evalue', 'pident'))
fasta_df3_sorted = fasta_df3.sort_values(by='qseqid', ascending = True)
fasta_df3_grouped = fasta_df3_sorted.groupby('qseqid')

for qseqid, fasta_df3_sorted in fasta_df3_grouped:
    subj3_pident_max = str(fasta_df3_grouped['pident'].max())
    subj3_pident_min = str(fasta_df3_grouped['pident'].min())
    current_gene = str(qseqid)
    with open(dir_output+outputall_file+".txt","a") as gene_list:
            gene_list.write("\n"+"subj3: {} \t {} \t {}".format(current_gene,
            subj3_pident_max, subj3_pident_min))
            gene_list.close()
```

Comment: I can't reproduce, but I can say, when you use `with open('filename, 'a') as file:` you don't need to close the file. It is closed for you. Would remove the `gene_list.close()` call, maybe it's being closed before it's flushing the write to the file.

Comment: Thank you for your hint but unfortunately this didn´t solve the problem :(